# JQuery wrap span around elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following html markup:

```
<div data-type="checkbox" class="widget_type_checkbox">
 <div>
    <div class="helptext">help text</div>
    <div class="validationMessage" style="display: none;">Error message</div>
    <input id="widget_chk_I095Q7N6" type="checkbox" name="chk_I095Q7N6" required="" value="true" >
    <label for="widget_chk_I095Q7N6">My checkbox</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

For all checkboxes with class `widget_type_checkbox` I want to wrap the input and label inside a  span as follows:

```
<div data-type="checkbox" class="widget_type_checkbox">
  <div>
    <div class="helptext">help text</div>
    <div class="validationMessage" style="display: none;">Error message</div>
    <span>
       <input id="widget_chk_I095Q7N6" type="checkbox" name="chk_I095Q7N6" required="" value="true" >
       <label for="widget_chk_I095Q7N6">My checkbox</label>
    </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

The following doesn't work:

```
$(".widget_type_checkbox").find("> div > span").not(":has(span)").find('input').next().andSelf().wrap('<span>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

1. [`andSelf()`](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) deprecated, use [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead.
2. `wrap()` wraps all elements separately, use `wrapAll()` instead.
3. `"> div > span"` selector starts with `>` is invalid

```js
$(".widget_type_checkbox :not(span) > input").each(function() {
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll("<span>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-type="checkbox" class="widget_type_checkbox">
  <div>
    <div class="helptext">help text</div>
    <div class="validationMessage" style="display: none;">Error message</div>
    <input id="widget_chk_I095Q7N6" type="checkbox" name="chk_I095Q7N6" required="" value="true">
    <label for="widget_chk_I095Q7N6">My checkbox</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-type="checkbox" class="widget_type_checkbox">
  <div>
    <div class="helptext">other help text</div>
    <div class="validationMessage" style="display: none;">Error message</div>
    <input id="widget_chk_I095Q7N7" type="checkbox" name="chk_I095Q7N7" required="" value="true">
    <label for="widget_chk_I095Q7N7">My checkbox</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you have multiple checkboxes the above code ends up moving the next checkbox inside the div of the first checkbox - see my update to you code where I've added another checkbox?

Comment: @adam78 That's not mentioned. Anyway, just do the same using `each()`. Check updated answer.